# C++Builder 64-bit Clang gives Unresolved external 'Vcl::Controls::TWinControl::GetDPIForDesigner()' for legacy forms

Tags: c++builder, vcl

We're porting some projects from an older version of C++Builder (10.1 32-bit) to 11.0 64-bit.  We created new, separate projects (all 141 of them!) and configured and added source to them.  Just about all the forms are giving this and other errors related to the VCL. Is there some conversion step we're missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do a clean build of all components included in the project?

Comment: The 64-bit version is a separate project group with each project created from scratch, then added the source files from the original projects.

Comment: Ok, and there are no references (paths in project files etc) to the old project from the new? I remember having some similar troubles a long time ago. I think I found the culprit by using `grep` for an old path in the whole directory structure of the new project :-)

Comment: Bingo!  When the 64-bit projects were created Builder put a lot of hard-coded paths in the .cbproj files (why????).  I cloned the project to a different folder, it dragged all those paths with it.  Don't know yet if it'll solve the problem but at least have a way forward.  Thanks!

Comment: Lovely! You're welcome! Yeah, I was a bit confused about that when it bit me too :-) I've also tried to always have relative paths in the project files but sometimes they get converted to absolute somehow.